# Pandas increasing column values conditional to another column

Tags: python, pandas

What's wrong with this approach

```py
df['max'] = np.where((df[df['category'] == 'basket']['width'] == 0), df['max']+10, df['max'])
```

so essentially I would like to update `df['max']` based on the condition where `df['category']` equals basket and the width of those equals `0`. If this is the case I would like to increase all `df['max']` values by `10` if not I would just like to keep it the same.

This returns the following error

```py
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (17,) (55,) (55,)
```

Input

```py
    max    category   width
0   181     basket     0  
1   745     basket     10
```

desired output

```py
    max    category   width
0   191     basket     0  
1   745     basket     10
```

Comment: post the sample input

Comment: With the input you provided, your solution works

Answer (score 1):

With given input this worked on my side.

```
df["max"] = np.where((df["category"]=="basket")&(df["width"]==0), df["max"]+10, df["max"])
print(df)

   max category  width
0  191   basket      0
1  745   basket     10
```